# Load pdf from remote url to send as Mandrill attachment

Tags: javascript, pdf, parse-platform, mandrill

I am trying to load a Pdf in Cloud Code and send it as an attachment with mandrill.

As mandrill needs a base64 encoded string for the attachment I use Buffer to change the encoding.

The result right now is an Pdf attachment that cannot be opened and I think the error is caused by my recoding.

I guessed the text returned from the get request is utf8 but I'm not sure.

Any suggestions?

var Buffer = require('buffer').Buffer;

```
function loadPdf(pdfUrl) {
  var promise = new Parse.Promise();

  Parse.Cloud.httpRequest({
    method: 'GET',
    url: pdfUrl,
    success: function (httpResponse) {
      // Put text into buffer
      var buf = new Buffer('httpResponse.text', 'utf8');
      // encode text with base64
      promise.resolve(buf.toString('base64'));
    },
    error: function (httpResponse) {
      console.error(httpResponse);
      console.error("Token Request failed with response code " + httpResponse.status);
    }
  });
  return promise;
}
```

the result of this function is put into

```
"attachments": [
    {
        "type": "application/pdf",
        "name": "test.pdf",
        "content": encodePdfText
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

I had the same problem recently, try the following code, make sure httpResponse.text is in utf8...

```
"content": new Buffer(httpResponse.text.toString('base64')).toString()
```